# A complex valued function sending a finite set to a finite set

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces

Let $f$ a multi-valued function defined on the whole extended complex plane, which sends a finite set $A$ to a finite set $B$, that is, $f(A)=B$ and $f^{-1}(B)=A$.

Both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ may have only algebraic branch points or poles. For $f$, the set of its branch points and poles, if any, is a subset of $A$.
For $f^{-1}$, the set of its branch points and poles, if any, is a subset of $B$. Everywhere else, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are holomorphic.

Does there exist such a function $f$, if $A=\{0,1,4,\infty\}$ and $B=\{0,1,\infty\}$?

Note that the question is answered in positive for a function $g$, if $A=\{0,1,2,\infty\}$ and $B=\{0,1,\infty\}$, in which case $g(z)=1-(z-1)^2$.

Also note that the question may be always answered in positive if there is no requirement for the location of branch points. In such a case, the function $f$ can be implicitly defined by the equation $x(x-1)(x-4)=y(y-1)$, where $y=f(x)$.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessin_d%27enfant if you have not heard of them.

Comment: not sure exactly what is the question; you want $f$ to be single-valued entire and only $g$ to have branch points

Comment: @Conrad - I did not say that $f$ is single valued, both $f$ and its inverse may be multi-valued.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements? In this case there is at least one element in $B$ that corresponds to two elements in $A$, so how would I define $f^{-1}$?

Comment: @Andrei - in the question an example of such multi-valued function is included for the case when the requirement for the location of branch points is removed: $x(x-1)(x-4)=y(y-1)$.

Comment: That implicitly defined $f$ has transcendental branch point(s)?

Comment: I mean, I'm trying to understand why it does have transcendental branch points.

Comment: So the function related to $x(x-1)(x-4) = y(y-1)$ has at least one branch point which is not algebraic? Or its inverse does? How do you know?

Comment: @aschepler - no, $x(x−1)(x−4)=y(y−1)$
 is determined by a bivariate polynomial, therefore it does not have transcendental branch points. However, its certain algebraic branch points are the solutions to the equation $x(x−1)(x−4)=\frac{1}{2}$, and so the branch points are not a subset of $\{0,1,4,\infty\}$, therefore this multivalued function does not satisfy the condition that branch points must be a subset of A.

Comment: Oh, of course. I was too focused on the wrong thing.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment: $x(x−1)(x−4)=-\frac{1}{4}$.